# Protect 555 timer from high voltage

Tags: high-voltage

I built a circuit which I strapped one electrode to the bottom of my shoe, and the other to my leg. This circuit consists of a high voltage DC supply in my pocket driven by a 555 timer. When it works, I am able to make static sparks to objects with a capacitance to ground and huge sparks from my finger to grounded objects. The issue is that I have to keep replacing the 555 timer because high voltage must be getting back into it. What is the best way to protect the timer from high voltage and is that likely the cause? The whole circuit is powered by 9vdc.

[image]

Comment: 9VDC is not high voltage.

Comment: It would really help if you provided a schematic

Comment: The output is high voltage though.

Comment: are you charge-pumping it? Voltage doubling? Either way a schematic would be nice, but in any case a few clamping diodes should protect it.

Comment: Use clamping diodes (classic use case, for inductive loads), and perhaps separate the 555 from the switching FET using a dual BJT push-pull driver circuit.

Comment: I dont understand the need of such high current mossfet, since it's high voltage->low current output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a combination of clamps and separation by other semiconductors being in the way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9962B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Something like that - to protect the 555 pin from inductive kickback, output voltage swings, separation by the totem pole driving circuit (which is a nice high-power fast switching bonus too) and clamp over the MOSFET to protect that, plus a clamp over the transformer.

Its as little overkill, but I think it's crazy enough to work! I hope others can critque/improve upon this suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now that I am thinking about it, the 555 timer could have been damaged simply by the high voltage out touching one of the pins in the form of my leg through the pocket. I will try that idea and also add more insulation.

Comment: @skyler yes wrapping the control circuit in insulation (electrical) tape would help too

Comment: D4 might be a problem, since the circuit seems to rely on a high voltage spike when M1 turns off, and ringing, lots of ringing.

Comment: @gsills i've not done any of these particular (transformer based) circuits before, so if D4 affects it negatively then it could be omitted!

Comment: It's kind of a wild circuit. M1 avalanche diode could get hit at every turn off.

Comment: @gsills D3 is only there to protect the FET from the pulsing transformer - having an external diode is far better than relying on the weak and slow body diode inside M1

Comment: Oh, I was talking about the one built into the FET. Avalanche rated FETs have a built in zener, kind of like the ring diodes built into schottky diodes. Most higher voltage FETs these days are avalanche rated. Like for example, the IRF530 is avalanche rated for 8.8mJ.

Comment: @gsills ah righto. Yes well, that's a flyback pulse circuit for ya! As crude as it gets!

Comment: why both of the BJTs are PNP?

Comment: @Unknown123  that's a mistake while i was quickly putting the circuit diagram together.. the top one Q1 should be NPN

Comment: simulation has errors and cannot be ran

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds  yes, the schematic is not set up for simulation. Build this in LTSpice or something, if you actually want to simulate and test this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your 555 cheaply by using a diode from the supply to the primary transformer winding and clamping the primary with a zener.  The zener will shunt any high voltage kickback on the primary, and the supply feeding diode will block any fast reverse voltage spikes that are too fast for the zener to shunt out. If you don't have a zener, you could use about 4-5 LED's in series (depending on your supply voltage) to shunt the high voltage back EMF in the primary (and it looks cooler than a zener). Next a diode from the GND plane of the 555 circuit could be used to isolate it from any reverse voltage. The last bit of protection I would add is a diode from output (3) of the 555 to the base of the driving transistor.

*A note on the schematic, I chose the components arbitrarily. For example the zener in the schematic is Vz = 5.1 which wouldn't work with a 12V supply. You'll want a Vz of at least 15V if the supply voltage is 12V.

I typically use a 2N3055 BJT to drive the primary of an auto-ignition coil to produce some awesome sparks, and it works pretty well. A curious experiment might be adding a ceramic capacitor across the primary; you'll have yourself a class C amplifier and possible RF generator. Just make sure the voltage rating of the capacitor is above the clamping voltage of your primary shunting zener or else you might blow the capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCLxjL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: but a zener is meant to keep a steady voltage, which is precisely not the point of the primary...I dont get it

Answer (score 0):

Since you're operating near the absolute maximum voltage of the 555, I suspect inductance in the layout may be causing power supply spikes.

I suggest a 7812 regulator (78L12 might be okay) to supply the 555 **only**, and parallel that 470uF electrolytic with 1uF to 10uF ceramic.

Comment: +1 good idea about the extra filter capacitors. The 470uF won't be fast enough to suppress fast transient voltages which are most likely the ones killing the 555 timer.

Comment: How is a 7812 going to be useful?  The OP said he is powering the circuit off of 9v.

Comment: @tcrosley The schematic says 12-16V. A 7812 would help even with 9V because it has a much higher max input voltage, but the 1.5V drop would not be ideal. In that case, I suggest a 12V unipolar TVS directly across the 555 power.

Answer (score 0):

I use a 555 timer output 3 at 17 volt instead of V1. I guess the high voltage surges don't pass the capacitor. 555 doesn't die after repeated use.

Here is my little demo: https://youtu.be/HxOOhTiIQps